# Send Java File object to a Server over Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, file, serialization, objectoutputstream

Hello I am trying to send a Java File Object over a socket to a server which will then store it in a database. Currently I have created a FileBean which stores the File object in it. I then use an ObjectOutputStream to writeObject() the FileBean to the Server. However, it seems as though the File object only contains a reference to the actual data, so the Server fails to actually get the data.

Is there a way to serialize the File object to be sent over the socket using something like an objectoutput stream? or does this require to writing of the file into a buffer and sending that across the socket?

any help and code examples is apprecaited

Answer (score 3):

A file is a path, not much more. And totally worthless to a server on a different machine.

This is all the state a file has (taken from the Java 1.6 source of `java.io.File`):

```
/**
 * This abstract pathname's normalized pathname string.  A normalized
 * pathname string uses the default name-separator character and does not
 * contain any duplicate or redundant separators.
 *
 * @serial
 */
private String path;

/**
 * The length of this abstract pathname's prefix, or zero if it has no
 * prefix.
 */
private transient int prefixLength;
```

You will have to read the file's contents (probably as a byte array) and send them to the server.

Comment: +1: Put another way, the File object is only useful if the path/directory is mounted on both machines the same. e.g. using NFS.  The important point is it doesn't not transfer the contents of the file, only its path. Note: If you use a relative path, it will remain a relative path on the receiver side, so the absolute path might not be the same.

Comment: would I be able to output the file into a byte array, place that byte array into a Serializable object, and then send it through the socket to the server?

Comment: @user428810 yes, and a byte array is in itself Serializable, so you woudn't have to wrap it in anything else